# Converting value into String based on Column Metadata from database

Tags: java

I have a `SqlRowSet` object named `resultSet` coming into my method after a database call.

My task is based on the type of the object, do a proper `String` conversion of the object.

I have written a switch case for this as below:

```
if (resultSet != null) {
   // for every row in the resultset
   while (resultSet.next()) {
       int colCount = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
       for (int index = 1; index <= colCount; index++) {
         // get the type of the column and convert to string
         switch (resultSetMetaData.getColumnType(index)) {
           case Types.VARCHAR:
           case Types.CHAR:
           case Types.LONGVARCHAR:

           if (resultSet.getString(index) == null) {
             currTempValue = resultSet.getString(index);
            // above line seems to be incorrect
     } else {
        currTempValue = resultSet.getString(index).trim();
     }
     break;

           case Types.INTEGER:
           case Types.BIGINT:
           case Types.SMALLINT:

           if (resultSet.getString(index) == null) {
         currTempValue = Integer.toString(resultSet.getInt(index));
        // above line seems to be incorrect
    } else {
         currTempValue = Integer.toString(resultSet.getInt(index)).trim();
    }
    break;

          case Types.DOUBLE:
          case Types.DECIMAL:
          case Types.REAL:

          if (resultSet.getString(index) == null) {
        currTempValue = Double.toString(resultSet.getDouble(index));
              // above line seems to be incorrect
            } else {
        currTempValue = Double.toString(resultSet.getDouble(index)).trim();
    }
    break;

          case Types.DATE:
    if (resultSet.getString(index) == null) {
        currTempValue = resultSet.getDate(index).toString();
       // above line seems to be incorrect
    } else {
        currTempValue = resultSet.getDate(index).toString().trim();
    }
    break;

          case Types.TIMESTAMP:
    if (resultSet.getString(index) == null) {
        currTempValue = resultSet.getTimestamp(index).toString();
        // above line seems to be incorrect
    } else {
        currTempValue = resultSet.getTimestamp(index).toString().trim();
    }
    break;

          case Types.TIME:
    if (resultSet.getString(index) == null) {
         currTempValue = resultSet.getTime(index).toString();
        // above line seems to be incorrect
    } else {
         currTempValue = resultSet.getTime(index).toString().trim();
    }
          break;

          case Types.BLOB:
          case Types.CLOB:
       currTempValue = "BLOB-CLOB";
    break;

          default:
        currTempValue = resultSet.getString(index).trim();
          break;
       } // switch
       } // for
     }// while
   }// if
```

The issue is how do I handle the null values in the resultSet properly.

In the code above I have put in comments as "above line seems to be incorrect". What will be the proper way of handling this ?

Comment: if resultSet.getString(index) is null, then nothing to do, right? just set currTempValue =null; or currTempValue  = ""; unless i am missing something

Comment: or based on your business module, you can consider null Integer as "0" or "-1", and null date as "1/1/1900"...etc